# Cookie pop-ups are repeatedly displayed on international sites & translations are not reflected and displayed in English

Tags: bug, status-completed, cookies, international-sites, cookie-consent-dialog

#### Problem #1

Translations are not reflected on the cookie pop-up screen on international sites and each meta site.
(We should have translated these strings.)

https://ja.stackoverflow.com
https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com
https://ru.stackoverflow.com
https://es.stackoverflow.com

[image]

#### Problem #2

Once access an international site after deleting cookies, even if I click "Accept" in the pop-up, the It repeats each time move from page to page.

Comment: About #2 that's most likely because you block cookies (browser setting) hence the site can't track the fact you accepted the cookies, try to change the settings or whitelist the site in the browser. (Note you have to allow third party domain cookielaw.org)

Comment: @ShadowWizardLoveZelda no,  I can reproduce this in my setup and I don't have issues on any other site. It is just the mentioned domains that cause issues.

Answer (score 5):

**[UPDATE 1]** The repeatedly displayed issue should now be resolved. The team is still workin on the translations issue. I'll update the thread again and tag as [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) once that has been fixed.

**[UPDATE 2]** The translations issue has now been resolved. Marking post as [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

---

Thanks for the report. The team is aware and working on the issue. I'll update this answer when this has been resolved. Thanks!