# Choosing "Necessary cookies only" doesn't prevent appearing of cookie notice after page refresh

Tags: bug, stack-overflow, localization, cookies, international-sites

Since yesterday choosing "Necessary cookies only" option on cookie notice doesn't prevent this notice appearing again and again after page refresh:

> [image]

Reproducible on all non-English Stack Overflow sites ([Russian](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/), [Portuguese](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/), [Japanese](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/), [Spanish](https://es.stackoverflow.com/)) unless you do the same on main [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/). After clicking "Necessary cookies only" on [enSO](https://stackoverflow.design/brand/copywriting/naming/), all other mentioned sites stop displaying the notice.

Comment: I was able to reproduce that the cookie dialog is redisplayed upon refresh after selecting "Necessary cookies only" in a fresh profile without any extensions or userscripts on Firefox 121.0.1 on [ru.so]. The cookie dialog was not redisplayed under the same conditions on [meta.stackexchange.com](https://meta.stackexchange.com).

Comment: I have already reported the same issue. https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/396179

Comment: @cubick yes it's the same bug, you could also flag as duplicate, sending this to the close review queue.